# What is the difference between CreateToken and WriteToken

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, jwt

As mentioned, in .Net core we use

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    
return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Here what is the difference between `CreateToken` and `WriteToken`?

Comment: In short: `WriteToken` returns a valid, parsed, encoded JSON Web Token as a string while a `CreateToken` will give you an **object** that contains token data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CreateToken** method create security token based on the specified token descriptor and return [securitytoken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytoken?view=netframework-4.8) object class.

**WriteToken** method returns string, i.e serializes the specified security token to a string.